# Visualisation of the reciprocal of an continued fraction?

Tags: analysis, continued-fractions, visualization

If: $$a=\cfrac{l}{m+\cfrac{n}{o+\cfrac{p}{q+\cdots}}}$$

Then could you help me visualize $1/a$? I really don't understand it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your continued fraction is very generic, in fact it specifies only $c_0 = 0$ and $b_1 = 1$ (compare with Batominovski's expansion) the general form 
$$
x 
= \frac{1}{a} 
= c_0 + \cfrac{b_1}{c_1+\cfrac{b_2}{c_2+\cfrac{b_3}{c_3+\cdots}}}
$$

How to visualize such a limit process?

For specific values of the coefficients $a_i$ and $b_i$ one might plot the sequence of the fraction values
\begin{align}
x_0 &= c_0 \\
x_1 &= c_0 + \cfrac{b_1}{c_1} \\
x_2 &= c_0 + \cfrac{b_1}{c_1 + \cfrac{b_2}{c_2}} \\
 & \vdots
\end{align}
for increasing index $i$.

If the coefficients are repetitive, e.g. $b_i = b$, $c_i = c$, then we can express the values as 
\begin{align}
x_1 &= \phi(c) = \phi^1(c) \\
x_2 &= \phi(\phi(c)) = \phi^2(c) \\
x_3 &= \phi(\phi(\phi(c))) = \phi^3(c) \\
 & \vdots
\end{align}
with 
$$
\phi(x) = c + \frac{b}{x}
$$
For specific values of $b$ and $c$ we could plot this as a fixed point iteration.

[image: fixed point iteration]
[(Larger image version)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7m7U.png)

The above image shows the iteration for $c=2$ and $b=1$ which converges to $1+\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

What about $\cfrac{1}{a}=\cfrac{1}{0+\cfrac{l}{m+\cfrac{n}{o+\cfrac{p}{q+\ldots}}}}$?  In fact, I don't know what you mean by "visualization."

Comment: That's kind of the elementary solution, right.

Comment: HINT: only $l$ is on the denomerater

Comment: What the **** does "visualization" mean?

Comment: @AAron $l$ is not in denominator.

Comment: for $1/a, l$ is on the denominator